# What do call your term set when LOCATION is already being used OOTB

Tags: site-column, term-store, term

I've read that it's not advised to rename OOTB site columns.

I'm interested to hear thoughts on the LOCATION column. It's a single line of text and gives maximum flexibility for the user to type in anything.

We're planning our deployment and Location to us means Region>Country>Office and we're thinking like that for our term set and terms. We really want to use LOCATION as it's the most obvious name for where something is located. We're now looking at clunky workarounds such as a site column called PLACE.

How are you doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are mainly worried about the name that the user will see, you can set the Display name and set the internal name to something else.

If you are doing this point and click, I recommend creating the column with the name Place for example, or maybe projectName_Column (e.g CannonFodder_Location). Once you have saved the column, by going back into it, if you changed the name, it will only change the display name, the internal name will still be the name you first called it. To prove this, right click on the column and select properties. If you scroll through the address URL you will see the value field=CannonFodder_Location or whatever you originally called it.

If you wish to do this in code, then I recommend you follow my blog http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/creating-a-site-column-with-managed-metadata/

As this will show you how to do it programmatically. Just set your internal name to Place or projectName_Column, and set your display name to Location.

Comment: Thanks for your help and apologies for not posting sooner.

Comment: If my answer worked for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer is useful. Thanks.